# Execute external command and wait for it to finish under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, execute

Easy question: what is the easiest way to execute an external program (with parameters) from C++ (using g++ and Linux)? Is there an easier way rather than doing fork/exec and waiting? I just need to execute the command and wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kind of depends on how much you want to interact with the program.

If not at all, you can easily just use `system("....");`

If you want some I/O then you can use `popen();`

And if even that is not enough, you will end up will `fork()`, `exec()`, `wait()`, `dup()` and other functions from this family.

Answer (score 2):

The [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) function:

```
#include 

int main (void)
{
        system("ls /home");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I have learnt to use [screen](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/) command a lot, especially for long running scripts. It may be bit of an overkill for you, but it should definitely do the job in this case.

Comment: I am extremely disappointed with this answer.  It's not even remotely close.  If I could down vote, I would do it until my mouse started to bleed.